# Requesting Proof of Data Deletion

Tags: data-protection, data-ownership, data-storage

This questions covers the law and tech.
If I delete my account at Facebook or any company with a website service, can I ask to be provided proof of data having been deleted in some form provided by the company?

Could I send a letter asking for some official receipt of data deletion.

Any suggestions for going about such a request?  Read the TOS/EULA I suppose?

I've worked in IT, there are many logs and databases where data could just sit around.  Typically accounts would be removed after 30 days or so.

Is there any legal standing to ask for proof?

Or is this all new and uncharted areas of tech and law?

Comment: What would you consider proof?  You are literally asking for something to be deleted or anonymised - unless they give you free access to their entire system so you can verify it yourself, providing “proof” is going to be difficult here.  Are you rather just looking for some document you can hold up in court should your details later be leaked when they should have been deleted?

Comment: Yes, what kind of document can they provide to me that could be use as legal proof, some letter of acknowledgement.  I don't know what is the standard protocol or if there even is one for users/customers.